# В приложении на flutter криво работает Youtube

Tags: flutter, youtube

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста как можно настроить youtube в приложении. Проблема в том, что кнопки не нажимаются, перемотать, увеличить экран и т.д. Как будто сенса сбита, жмешь на паузу он перематывает видео

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Какой пакет используете? Какой у вас код?